# Using Get-TlsCipherSuite in PowerShell & Server 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

My PowerShell TLS module doesn't seem to contain the cmdlet `Get-TlsCipherSuite`:

```
PS> (Get-Module tls).ExportedCommands

Key                         Value
---                         -----
Disable-TlsSessionTicketKey Disable-TlsSessionTicketKey
Enable-TlsSessionTicketKey  Enable-TlsSessionTicketKey
Export-TlsSessionTicketKey  Export-TlsSessionTicketKey
New-TlsSessionTicketKey     New-TlsSessionTicketKey
```

But I'm not sure how I can update it.

I am on PS 5.1

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14409  1018
```

I have attempted

```
PS> Update-Module tls
Update-Module : Module 'tls' was not installed by using Install-Module, so it
cannot be updated.
```

***Edit:***

I think this is a limitation of Server 2012 R2 as the cmdlet is not listed under 2012 here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/?view=win10-ps

However, it is listed for 2016. Is there a way to import this command to 2012 R2?

Answer (score 7):

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010002 -Name Functions
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/?view=winserver2012r2-ps) the `TLS` module in Windows Server 2012 R2 doesn't have the cmdlet you're looking for. As far as I'm aware you cannot update the module without upgrading to a more recent Windows version.

Answer (score 4):

Arjun's answer is valid, but it uses the `Get-ItemPropertyValue` cmdlet, which is itself reserved for later PowerShell versions. A fully PowerShell 2.0-compliant version of the `Get-TLSCipherSuite` command is as follows:

```
(get-itemproperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010002 -Name Functions).Functions
```