# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod Could not create TLS/SSL secure channel

Tags: powershell, rest, ssl, tls1.2, invoke-restmethod

I'm calling Invoke-RestMethod in a PowerShell script to upload a zip archive to an Artifactory repository.
I tested the script from my local machine PowerShell ISE; upload complete without issue as expected. However, when I execute the script on the intended target machine, I'm seeing an error returned:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I've read numerous online posts related to this error; consensus appears to be to add the following line immediately before the Invoke-RestMethod call in the script:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3
```

I added this line but the issue persists.

Execution of the following PowerShell:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
```

returns:

> Ssl3, Tls, Tls11, Tls12
> suggesting that all available protocols are enabled.

My script snippet now looks like this:

```
$headers = @{"X-JFrog-Art-Api" = $artifactoryApiKey}        
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3

    $return=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -InFile $sourceFile -Method Put -Headers $headers
```

As stated above, this script executes without issue on my local machine.

.Net 4.6.1 installed on server returning error.

Comment: When nothing works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client sometimes you need to check the registry; this helped me in similar situations https://pastebin.com/GyBHmvjy (make a backup of the subtree in question first)

Answer (score 2):

I don't offer an explanation, but perhaps a solution for some.  I was having the same exact issue: PowerShell invoke-RestMethod worked locally but not when run from the intended (Windows 2012 R2) server.  I receive the same TLS/SSL error.  I read a lot about the [TLS handshake](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/explaining-ssl-handshake/) and other technotes, and tested suggestions like:

1. Setting the security protocol as noted in the original question
2. [Enabling TLS protocol in the registry](https://thesecmaster.com/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-and-tls-1-3-on-windows-server/)
3. [Listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447881/using-get-tlsciphersuite-in-powershell-server-2012-r2) and comparing Cipher Suites.

In the end, I couldn't get PowerShell to work.  HOWEVER, the rest call works from the server using curl.exe in command line.  If you see this, I recommend stop trying to troubleshoot PowerShell and [give curl a try](https://curl.se/windows/). I found [this](https://www.baeldung.com/curl-rest) and [this](https://devqa.io/curl-sending-api-requests/) helpful in writing my first curl.exe rest calls.